# Issue with bundler (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rake, redmine

When I run this command (step 5 of Redmine installation):

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

I get this error message:

```
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

But rake is already installed.
Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Notes:

1) 'bundle install --local' works fine

2) 'rake' didn't exist originally (what quite surprised me as I took the original redmine Gemfile), so I added the line. Same effect, sadly.

3) 'rake' alone works fine. It's when I write the whole command that I get this message

Comment: Have you tried `bundle install` before? It should install all dependencies.

Comment: Yes,  `bundle install --local`.
And it told me everything was installed correctly.

Comment: Is rake a dependency define in your gemfile, or is another gem dependent on it? If rake isn't a dependency, it will not exist inside of the scope of the bundle.

Comment: It didn't exist originally (what quite surprised me as I took the original redmine Gemfile), so I added the line. Same effect, sadly.

Comment: The problem isn’t that rake isn’t installed, but that the `rake` executable isn’t on your path. Check that the directory your gems executables are installed into is in your `$PATH` env variable.

Comment: Actually `rake` alone works fine. It's when I write the whole command that I get this message.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `bundle install`. It will download and install all gems required for running application.